# Node JS, Captcha Solving

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is my code!

```
const https = require('https');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')

// add recaptcha plugin and provide it your 2captcha token (= their apiKey)
// 2captcha is the builtin solution provider but others would work as well.
// Please note: You need to add funds to your 2captcha account for this to work
const RecaptchaPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha')

puppeteer.use(
  RecaptchaPlugin({
    provider: {
      id: '2captcha', token: '93...' },
    visualFeedback: true // colorize reCAPTCHAs (violet = detected, green = solved)
  })
  
async function login() {

    global.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 10,
        userDataDir: 'C:\\userData',
    });

global.page = await browser.pages();
    const setUserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36';

    var userAgent = require('user-agents');

    await page[0].setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());
    console.log("Going to Website");
    await page[0].goto("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo", {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
        console.log("Solving Captcha");

    await page[0].solveRecaptchas()

  await Promise.all([
    page[0].waitForNavigation()
  ])
}
```

This is a roughly my code, i have 2captcha balance
code above doesnt solve the captcha, it detects the captcha and turns it purple, but it doesnt solve the captcha, i need help

Comment: We need debugging details and more information. You can't post a chuck of code, say it "doesn't work" and hope for the best on here

Comment: what is debugging details? is it the cmd output?

Comment: What specific part of your code has an unwanted behavior? What solutions have you tried?

Comment: ive tried codes ive found on the internet, specific part of code is: await page[0].solveRecaptchas()

Answer (score 0):

After you got response from 2captcha, You have to call submit button manually using following code.

```
await page.waitForSelector('#recaptcha-demo-submit')
await page.click('#recaptcha-demo-submit')
```